# Tkinter .get() from entry gives weird values

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a simple GUI program using Tinter and Turtle where the goal is to draw a polygon. I ask the user for the number of sides and length of side. I made a simple GUI, but when I click the button to get the values I get very small decimal digit values and I can't figure out why.

```
import Tkinter as tk

def draw_polygon():
    num_of_sides.get()
    length_of_sides.get()

    print num_of_sides, length_of_sides

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Label(root, text='Number of Sides').grid(row=0)
tk.Label(root, text='Length of Sides').grid(row=1)

num_of_sides = tk.Entry(root)
num_of_sides.grid(row=0, column=1)

length_of_sides = tk.Entry(root)
length_of_sides.grid(row=1, column=1)

draw_button = tk.Button(root, text='Draw', command=draw_polygon)
draw_button.grid(row=3, column=1)

tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must assign the return value of `get()` to a variable.  Otherwise, you print the name of the widget, which by default is a point followed by a number.

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Label(root, text='Number of Sides').grid(row=0)
tk.Label(root, text='Length of Sides').grid(row=1)

num_of_sides = tk.Entry(root, name = "numOfSides")
num_of_sides.grid(row=0, column=1)

length_of_sides = tk.Entry(root, name = "lenOfSides")
length_of_sides.grid(row=1, column=1)

def draw_polygon():
    ns = num_of_sides.get()
    ls = length_of_sides.get()

    print ns, ls                
    print num_of_sides, length_of_sides

draw_button = tk.Button(root, text='Draw', command=draw_polygon)
draw_button.grid(row=3, column=1)

tk.mainloop()
```

Of course, you may comment or remove the second `print`, I left it for the explanation.  You may also remove the two `name=` arguments.

Comment: The argument `name` in `Entry` made my day :D +1